# Sun Studio Compiler: implicit function declaration: typeof

Tags: c, typeof, sunstudio

When attempting to compile mpd with Sun Studio compiler:

```
"client.c", line 438: warning: implicit function declaration: typeof
```

I tracked down the offending lines of code, in `dlist.h`:

```
#define list_for_each_entry(pos, head, member)                          \
        for (pos = list_entry((head)->next, typeof(*pos), member);      \
             &pos->member != (head);    \
             pos = list_entry(pos->member.next, typeof(*pos), member))
```

According to [typeof Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeof), it's a GCC extension. Is there a `typeof` equivalent in Sun Studio, or a way to emulate it?

Comment: Prove with #include <stddef.h> in Sun Studio 12 work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This article](http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/c_type.html#Introducing%20the%20typeof%20Keyword|outline) says `typeof` is introduced in Sun Studio 12.